# Best practices to separate concerns when accessing database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, design-patterns

I've been trying to improve the separation of concerns when it comes to applications that access a database (via Hibernate).

On one of the applications I've been using the following approach:

- Create services with business logic that have no connection/awareness of the database. They only communicate with GeneralDAO (and with other services);
- A GeneralDAO responsible for CRUD/find operations, and with methods that involve more complex database queries.

The problems I see with this approach are:

- GeneralDAO slowly becomes a God Object, when your application grows and require lots of specific database queries.
- Sometimes the more specific Services become only proxies to the GeneralDAO, since the method is simple and only requires a database query. See example 1.

**Example 1: Service is just a proxy**

BookService manages things related to books in the Library application. Let's consider 2 methods:

- archiveBook(Book)
- findByIsbn(String isbn)

In `archiveBook(Book)` there might be considerable business logic involved - we might imagine this involves calls to:

```
 distributionService.unbox(Book);
 archivalBook.archive(Book);
 librarianService.informNewBook(Book);
```

But `findByIsbn(String isbn)` is a lot more simple: it just needs to execute an SQL call to the database. So in this case I see two options:

1. Redirect the call to an object that can speak to the database to execute the query. For example generalDAO.findByIsbn(String isbn), that uses a db communication layer (in Hibernate it would use a sessionFactory or EntityManager) to execute the query.
2. Make that database layer available to the BookService, so that it executes the query itself

**Questions/opinions (first number identifies the option above):**

1.1. Isn't it strange to have 2 methods with the exact same signature, even if this is done to keep the BookService independent of the database layer (and ORM)?

1.2. How do you suggest avoiding The God anti-pattern? Would you suggest breaking the GeneralDAO into several DAOs depending on what the methods do? In this case, won't we risk needing to inject lots of DAOs into some Services, leading to a Service having too many objects injected into it?

2.1 What do you think of this alternative? Doesn't it break the "separation of concerns" by having the BookService be aware of objects at two different levels of abstraction (the DAO and the sessionFactory/EntityManager)?

3.1. Would you suggest any other approach/pattern/best practise?

Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays, I actually believe we should remove any database-business-knowledge from the DAO. The DAO should do what it is suposed to do, and it is to run queries agaisnt your database. Its easy to configure them to do Crud sql by themselves, but any query that goes beyong that should be handled by the business layer using an object that knows how to build queries. This way you don't have business-sql in your daos. I have tons of them in my job and they are a pain, not to mention that the business layer, most of time, just pass control to DAO instead of doing their own job.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.2. How do you suggest avoiding The God anti-pattern? Would you suggest breaking the GeneralDAO into several DAOs depending on what
>   the methods do? In this case, won't we risk needing to inject lots of
>   DAOs into some Services, leading to a Service having too many objects
>   injected into it?

Generally, a DAO class should handle a specific entity.
If one of your entities require many kinds of queries, you could divide it again into two or more DAOs by grouping them by common concern (for example : reading, writing, selecting on agregates, etc...) as you said.
If you have too many queries and too many DAO, maybe, you should check if you don't write almost the same queries in several methods. It it the case, use specification or Criteria API to allow the client to custom queries by parameters. If the queries are really different, you have various processings. So, using multiple DAOs seems a suitable solution. It avoids increasing the complexity and the rise of god objects.

> 1.1. Isn't it strange to have 2 methods with the exact same signature, even if this is done to keep the BookService independent of the
>   database layer (and ORM)?

When you divide you app in logic layers,  as you noticed, in some operations, some layers perform only delegation calls to the below layer. 
So in these cases, it is rather common to have method names which are the same. I would go further : it is a good practice to have the same name if it is just delegation call. Why do we create a variation in the conveyed behavior if they both address the same need?

> 2.1 What do you think of this alternative? Doesn't it break the "separation of concerns" by having the BookService be aware of objects
>   at two different levels of abstraction (the DAO and the
>   sessionFactory/EntityManager)?

BookService depends on DAOs but should not depend on sessionFactory/EntityManager which makes part of the DAO implementation.
BookService calls DAO which uses a sessionFactory/EntityManager.
If necessary, BookService may specify transactional details on itself or on its methods with @Transactional annotation.

> 3.1. Would you suggest any other approach/pattern/best practice?

- As you use Spring, try to rely on the Sping JPA repository (less boiler plate to handle for common cases and extensible class)
- Using specification or criteria patterns when you have several variants of some queries.

Comment: Thank you David. There are some interesting ideas here. Also thank you for the Spring JPA repository. I only became aware of this very recently, and am currently trying to figure out what changes it would require in an application that uses hibernate and sessionfactory (SF). Still need to figure out if Spring data is alternative or complementary to Hibernate, and also if I should first upgrade from SF to entityManager (and JPA queries) and afterwards integrate Spring Data.